# How to resize a /home partition in Kubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, kde, files, resize

I was distro hopping for awhile in the past few months, so in order to keep all of my files secure, I made a partition of around 50 GB named Files to store all of my files in, and still have them for quick and easy access. However, now that I've found a distribution I'm comfortable with (Kubuntu 11.10), I would like to remove this partition, and have all of my files in my /home folder, in order to more easily deal with these files.

I've moved all of my files in the partition to my /home folder (and still have plenty of room to spare), and now I'm trying to delete the partition and use the space for my /home folder. I can delete the partition just fine, however, I can't extend the /home folder into the unallocated space. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot]

In order to change the size of the /home partition, I need to unmount it. But, I am unable to unmount it! How do I best extend the size of the partition?

Answer (score 2):

Boot from live media so no partitions are mounted.  The ability to live extend partitions is the big bonus of using LVM.

If you use something like [resize2fs](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ext4grow.html) you should be able to do it without live media.

As long as your tool is doing an appropriate resize you should keep all your files.  This is why I prefer CLI for important operations over gui tools.  You never know exactly what they're doing.

Comment: If I do this, will my files still remain intact?

Comment: @devon yes, if used correctly (if yo tell the system to format the partition ...  ;) ). I used this method to resize a 500Gb disc w/o removing files. Btw...if the partition is full it might take same time since the system will try to move files around your system to create empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live CD, Ubuntu or the gparted live CD will do.

Start gpared.

You have to do this in two steps.

First expand (enlarge) your extended partition (sda1) -> apply changes

Second expand your home partition (sda6) -> apply changes.

When resizing partitions there is always a small risk that something may go wrong, you should have backups.

Answer (score 0):

Download the ISO here:http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html and create a UBCD or you can also create this on a bootable USB stick. Boot your PC from the CD or USB and run Partition Magic.